The response time for playlist requests is very slow, exceeding 1 minute (80 seconds)
Here is my code to load youtube playlistitem. It's working and I can get the result.
private static final int MAX_RESULTS_PER_PAGE = 50;
public static List<PlaylistItemSnippet> loadPlaylistItems(String playlistId) throws IOException {
    List<PlaylistItemSnippet> allItems = new ArrayList<>();
    YouTube youtube = YouTubeSingleton.getYouTube();

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();  // Start time for logging

    String nextPageToken = null;
    do {
        // Batch request for playlist items and status
        YouTube.PlaylistItems.List playlistItemsListRequest = youtube.playlistItems().list("snippet,status");
        playlistItemsListRequest.setPlaylistId(playlistId);
        playlistItemsListRequest.setMaxResults((long) MAX_RESULTS_PER_PAGE);
        playlistItemsListRequest.setPageToken(nextPageToken);
        playlistItemsListRequest.setKey(DeveloperKey.getDeveloperKey());

        // Execute the batched request
        PlaylistItemListResponse playlistItemListResponse = playlistItemsListRequest.execute();

        long apiCallDuration = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;  // Duration of API call
        Log.d("text", "API_call_duration_for_token " + ": " + apiCallDuration + " ms");

        List<PlaylistItemSnippet> snippets = new ArrayList<>();
        for (PlaylistItem item : playlistItemListResponse.getItems()) {
            // Get the snippet object from the PlaylistItem
            PlaylistItemSnippet snippet = item.getSnippet();
            snippets.add(snippet);

            PlaylistItemStatus status = item.getStatus();
            if (status != null && status.getPrivacyStatus().equals("public")) { // Check privacy status
                allItems.add(snippet);
                if (allItems.size() >= MAX_RESULTS_PER_PAGE) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        nextPageToken = playlistItemListResponse.getNextPageToken();
    } while (nextPageToken != null);

    return allItems;
}

I've also used direct http request with okhttp client.
But the trouble is here the time request response is very slow now. It's more than 80s. I don't know why ?
How to improve it ? User can't wait too long to get the result

This line:
List<PlaylistItemSnippet> snippets = new ArrayList<>();

is inside your do/while block. Leave it outside.
This might explain why you code takes too long. - because in every loop, the snippets list of type List<PlaylistItemSnippet> is clear - re-created.
Or even better, add the snippet item in the allItems list that you already have outside of the loop.
Not sure why you have these lines here:
if (allItems.size() >= MAX_RESULTS_PER_PAGE) {
   break;
}

Check closely your code.

I don't think this cause slow down the response. // Execute the batched request
PlaylistItemListResponse playlistItemListResponse = playlistItemsListRequest.execute(); -> It's stuck here . I mean seem youtube server hold time to response to client ?
